# Combine a LOT of JSON Files Into a Single One

Tags: json, bash, shell

I need to combine **a lot** of JSON Files into one .json

I have tried it with `jq` but it will not be in the format that I need. Maybe there is a option with `jq` that I have missed.

All the JSONS have the following structure.

```
{"skuReference":"1","quantity":"0","backlog":"0"}
```

The Output should be:

```
{"skuReference":"1","quantity":"0","backlog":"0"},
{"skuReference":"2","quantity":"0","backlog":"0"},
{"skuReference":"3","quantity":"0","backlog":"0"},
...
```

After every "single json" there should be a comma, to separate.

Comment: Is each `{ ... }` a single line in the input ?

Comment: Don't you want a leading `[` and a trailing `]` to make the "all" file into a valid JSON array?

Comment: That output's not valid JSON... You'd be better off just concating them all into JSON Lines format: https://jsonlines.org/ or using jq (or other) to generate a single array. Really not sure what would properly parse the format above as it's not valid anything...really.

Answer (score 3):

Using sed:

```
$ sed '$!s/$/,/' files*  # > out_file
```

It replaces the end-of-line (`s/$/`) with a comma for all but the last line (`$!`). So, if I got:

```
$ cat foo
{"skuReference":"1","quantity":"0","backlog":"0"}
$ cat bar
{"skuReference":"2","quantity":"0","backlog":"0"}
```

and I:

```
$ sed '$!s/$/,/' foo bar
{"skuReference":"1","quantity":"0","backlog":"0"},
{"skuReference":"2","quantity":"0","backlog":"0"}
```

Comment: Hey @james-brown, thanks for the answer. It works perfectly well, but I will get the response "argument list too long: sed". Is there a flag or a workaround for that problem?

Comment: Hmm, how many files do you have?

Comment: `find ./ -type f -name '*.json' -exec cat -- '{}' + | sed '$!s/$/,/'`

Comment: @Fravadona this solution works for the amount of files, but now the jsons are not separated by a comma.

Comment: @Scamus I get the commas in all lines but the last when testing it myself with 1128384 files

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
jq -s '[.[]]' *.json | tail -n +2 | head -n -1 | output.json
```

the head and tail are to remove the leading and trailing brackets, since jq will merge into a array type

Comment: works also with multi-line `{...}`

Comment: Not working for me. Maybe it works for a smaller amount of files, but unfortunately I have about 160k files.

Comment: @Scamus, edit your question; in it you need to specify that you have a massive number of files

Answer (score 2):

<sup>**Adapting @JamesBrown POSIX `sed` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70064755/3387716) for a massive number of files.**</sup>

###### Example:

- Let's create a few JSONs, each one containing the single line `{}`:

```sh
mkdir JSONs

for ((i=0; i<2097152; i++)); do echo '{}' > JSONs/$i.json; done
```

- Let's see of you can process them with a glob expansion in a command:

```
ls JSONs/*.json
# bash: /usr/bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

Woops, it's too much! We'll need to use a tool like `find` for processing this massive amount of files.

---

1. Let's try with `find -exec cat | sed`:

```sh
find JSONs -type f -name '*.json' -exec cat {} + | sed '$!s/$/,/' > JSONs.txt
```

```
wc -l JSONs.txt
# 2097152 JSONs.txt

grep -v '^{},$' JSONs.txt | wc -l
# 1

tail -n 1 JSONs.txt
# {}
```

Good, this solution works: there's only one line in `JSONs.txt` without comma -> the last one.

---

2. @JamesBrown Now let's try with `find | xargs sed`:

```sh
find JSONs -type f -name '*.json' | xargs sed '$!s/$/,/' > JSONs.txt
```

```
wc -l JSONs.txt
# 2097152 JSONs.txt

grep -v '^{},$' JSONs.txt | wc -l
# 296
```

Woops, we got `296` lines without comma here. The reason is that `xargs` has run several `sed` commands, each one with the maximum number of arguments allowed.